# Why doesn't jQuery code work in my php file?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm having difficulties in putting jquery plugin in my php file. I want to be able to prevent sending the form when the text field is empty, but it doesnt work.

PHP:

```
    <html>
    <head>    
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>

<?php


    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if(empty($_POST["login"])) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            $("form").submit(function(event){ 
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("submit prevented");
            });                 
            </script>';
        }else {
        $login = test_input($_POST['login']);
        }

    }
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post"> 
    Login: <input type="text" name="login"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The same script in my script file

```
$("form").submit(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("submit prevented");
});
```

works just fine, the problem is just i can't put it into my php and i think its because of the absence of jQuery.

Comment: are you sure that "jquery.js" is in the same folder and included in the file you want to run a jQuery function in

Comment: Is it because you have to wrap your code with jQuerys `.ready` handler?

Comment: doesnt help even if i have .ready handler

Answer (score 0):

Simply start with `$(document).ready()`, very good practice in jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("submit prevented");
  });
});
```

Comment: still it doesnt prevent the form from submitting, the script inside works and the jquery file is correct, but doesnt submit at all.

Comment: what exactly do do you want? ** `event.preventDefault();`** just prevent default html event from executing and instead execute what is in jquery. And it doesn't mean that it prevent a form at all from submitting pal. So what do you want?

Comment: i want the alert message, when the text field is blank, so when i click submit it doesnt submit and ot shows me the alertt message

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        $("form").submit(function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("submit prevented");
        });                 
        </script>';
```

That is not how you properly echo multi lines in PHP.
Check out heredoc . Example:

```
echo <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;

echo <<<"FOOBAR"
Hello World!
FOOBAR;
```

There is also nowdoc but no parsing is done inside the block.

```
echo <<<'EOD'
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using nowdoc syntax.
EOD;
```

Comment: this is prolly a right thing to do, however im new with programming and i want to make sure something more basic works at first, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing it, just close the braces.  Also $(document).ready

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if(empty($_POST["login"])) {;?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("form").submit(function(event){ 
              event.preventDefault();
              alert("submit prevented");
            });             
          });    
         </script>

    <?php }else {
    $login = test_input($_POST['login']);
    }
};?>
```

Comment: While that will work, it is rather ugly coding and can get confusing when debugging.

Comment: Well I think this site is dedicated more to producing working code, than preventing ugly code...lol   Just look at wordpress.  If ugly code was a sin, wordpress would be satan

Comment: Aye... which is why you haven't gotten any down votes. Wordpress is a cookie cutter template for non programmers... what do you expect?

Comment: I agree fully. :) but I would also argue that on the user facing front-end side of wordpress it functions just beautifully.  Which ultimately proves that even though the code is hideous, it still functions as intended.  Just like the above code....lol   But I do get what you're saying though. I love beautiful code just as much as  any programmer

Comment: Specifics?? Errors logged? anything besides 'doesn't work' will help